# JS: Are strings really primitive types? If so, how is this possible?

Tags: javascript

In my data structures class I learned that under the hood strings are really arrays of characters, which means that strings must be a referential variable as opposed to a primitive variable. However, in JS this is not the case - strings are indeed considered primitive types in JS. What makes this even more surprising is the fact that JS was written in C, same as Python and Ruby- both of which treat strings are referential variable.

Are strings really primitive types? If so, how is this possible?

Comment: How is the link given relevant here?

Comment: Why is it suprising that JS was written in C? Why would the way C handles strings have any effect on how languages written in it handle strings?

Comment: JavaScript (ECMAScript, really) is a *language specification*. What language you use to implement it has no significance whatsoever.

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant links in questions and answers. If you do it regularly, the SE network will...route around you...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, strings are really primitives. Well, the ones that aren't objects are. The language used to create a compiler or interpreter doesn't need to have any effect on how the language being compiled or interpreted does things.

People are sometimes confused by the fact that although they're primitives, they have properties (like `length`) and methods (like `toLowerCase`), which makes it seem like they'd be objects. So let's explore that.

When you see an expression accessing a property of a string, perhaps a method:

```
str = str.toLowerCase();
```

...what happens is that the string primitive is promoted to a `String` object, and then that object's method is used, and then the temporary object is thrown away. This is built into the language, covered (in turgid prose) in [§11.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) and (more to the point) [§8.7.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1), in Step 1 where it uses the abstract [`ToObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) method.

This works for most of the primitives (strings, numbers, and booleans). The other two (`null` and `undefined`) have no object equivalent.

This behavior even works when you *assign* a property to a primitive string, but since the temporary object that's created is thrown away, the property disappears immediately. E.g., this is valid and will run:

```
var str = "foo";
str.someSpecialProperty = "bar";
console.log(typeof str.someSpecialProperty); // "undefined"
```

...but the object that property is added to disappears immediately, making it effectively a no-op, hence the property being undefined at the end (because it's not on the *second* temporary object that was created).

---

When I said "Well, the ones that aren't objects are" what I meant is that you can explicitly create a string *object*:

```
var strObj = new String();
```

That's an object, not a primitive:

```js
var str = "foo";
snippet.log("typeof str = " + typeof str);       // "string"
var strObj = new String("foo");
snippet.log("typeof strObj = " + typeof strObj); // "object"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

It's extremely rare to want to do that, but you can.

Comment: yep, so-called **auto-boxing**

Comment: @Leo: It's *similar* to Java's auto-boxing, but slightly different, and I've never heard it called that term applied to JavaScript.

Comment: The language spec doesn't use that phrase. It is commonly used when somebody tried to explain it to people (who are familiar with other OOP languages) how it is going, although not 100% accurate :)

Comment: Is a string an array of characters under the hood?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4: It doesn't matter, and could easily vary from implementation to implementation. But I can't immediately see why an implementation would do anything other than use an array of 16-bit words, as JavaScript's strings are defined as being A) A series of UTF-16 *code units* (not Unicode code *points*, aka characters), and B) immutable.